# Display entries from a database, list them from newest to oldest and stop after a certain amount?

Tags: php, mysql, database, post, blogs

I have the following tables in my DB:

1. id
2. title
3. heading
4. content
5. date
6. tags
7. username
8. like
9. dislike
10. comments

I have the database hooked up so that it will show what's in the rows, but I don't know how to  make it so that it will generate and list a "post block" every time a new entry is made. I would also like to list them from newest posts to oldest, all while limiting the posts to 10-20 per page.

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','','andrewryan') or die('error connection');

mysql_select_db('andrewryan');

$query = "Select * FROM entry";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$username = $row['username'];
$title = $row['title'];
$heading = $row['heading'];
$content = $row['content'];
$tags = $row['tags'];
$like = $row['like'];
$dislike = $row['dislike'];
$comment = $row['comment'];
$date = $row['date'];
?>
```

I also have another page with just one block of html. Which is the post framework with all the variables given where they are needed. Any reference for what I'm going for can be found at this link if it helps: [HERE](http://andrewryan.me)

Comment: Could you post the code, too?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What have you tried? Check out `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html Downvoted because it appears that you haven't done any due diligence.

Comment: There's a few million questions/answers on this site on how to do pagination of DB results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the query:

```
// Tildes on date since it is a keyword and some databases will error out without them
// Order by date is if you are using a compatible storing: unix timestamp or DateTime field
$query = "Select * FROM entry ORDER BY `date` DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$rowCount = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $username[$rowCount] = $row['username'];
    $title[$rowCount] = $row['title'];
    $heading[$rowCount] = $row['heading'];
    $content[$rowCount] = $row['content'];
    $tags[$rowCount] = $row['tags'];
    $like[$rowCount] = $row['like'];
    $dislike[$rowCount] = $row['dislike'];
    $comment[$rowCount] = $row['comment'];
    $date[$rowCount] = $row['date'];
    $rowCount++;
}
```

This is as far as showing the posts:

```
// limit is used to show the max posts per page.
$limit = 20;

//The following for is for paging
for($i = 1; $i <= $numofpages; $i++){
    if($i == $page){
        echo $i . " ";
    }else{
        echo "<a href='page.php?page=" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</a> ";
    }
}

// The following is to show your post blocks
for($j = 0; $j < $limit; $j++){
    //This will give you the appropriate post for the page
    $temp = $j + (($page * $limit) - $limit);
    // Your code to show your post blocks
    echo $username[$temp]; //For example, just format for your site layout.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. SELECT all the fields that you are interested to fetch.
2. Use DATE_FORMAT function to format the date field and assign to a new alias.I named it ndate.

   1. Then ORDER BY ndate

SELECT username,title,heading,content,tags,like,dislike,comment,DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%M-%Y') AS ndate FROM entry ORDER BY ndate

fetch the date as $row['ndate']